# using fs.renameSync() changes file permission _ NodeJs

Tags: node.js, fs

I am trying to rename a sqlite file . after renaming I cannot insert data to it:

```
fs.renameSync(db_name, "some.db");

const db = new sqlite3.Database("some.db");

db.exec(`.....`);
```

error:

```
[Error: SQLITE_READONLY: attempt to write a readonly database] {
 errno: 8,
code: 'SQLITE_READONLY'
}
```

Comment: hey @Babak Abadkheir
Did you got any solution for this error?
I am also facing Error: SQLITE_READONLY: attempt to write a readonly database
while inserting record in db.sqlite3 database.

Comment: @JIGNESHPATEL yes my problem was fs.renameSync(). I used the async renaming method.